# Get X - TextFormField is not updating using getX and GetBuilder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to assign dynamic TextFormField values using another `TextFormField` using `AlertDialog` but it is assigning and updating value in every widget but when it comes to `textformField` widget it does not change the value inside the `textFormField`

**getx Controller**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LabourBulkController extends GetxController {
  List workersList = [];
  bool loading = false;
  getActiveLabours() async {
    loading = true;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = prefs.getString("token");
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    workersList.clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
      Map customerData = {
        "id": data['data'][i]['worker_id'],
        "name": data['data'][i]['worker_name'],
        "amount": 0,
      };
      workersList.add(customerData);
      update();
    }
    loading = false;
  }

  assignAtOnce(String amount) {
    for (var i = 0; i < workersList.length; i++) {
      workersList[i]['amount'] = amount;
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

**widget code**

```
 GetBuilder<LabourBulkController>(builder: (dx) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dx.workersList.length,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              const Icon(FeatherIcons.user),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 20,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "${dx.workersList[index]['name']} | ${dx.workersList[index]['amount'].toString()}",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                hintText: "Wages",
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.wallet,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                )),
                            initialValue:
                                dx.workersList[index]['amount'].toString(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              dx.workersList[index]['amount'] = value;
                              dx.refresh();
                            },
                          )
                        ]),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }),
```

** alert dialog **

```
  FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                return showDialog<void>(
                  context: context,
                  barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text('Enter Wages'),
                      content: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: ListBody(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _amountController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Enter Amount',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.currency_exchange,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onChanged: (v) {
                                _bulkController.assignAtOnce(v);
                              },
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: const Text("Assing Wages"))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
```

Comment: I would add a breakpoint  at this line`return ListView.builder` and check what data is pushed from controller to screen after `update` inside `assignAtOnce`

Comment: Sir value is being updated in the array but inital value is not updating in the  ```TextFormFieldWidget```. @blackkara

Comment: @swapnilmane did you resolve this? I am facing a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699131/getx-not-updating-list-of-textformfield-correctly).

Comment: I did not solve this problem. I just added a textField where I am showing the from Getx.