# Getx not updating list of TextFormField correctly

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using Getx and `ListView.builder` in a Flutter Web app to render a list of items with `TextFormField`. Each rendered item has a delete button. When I click to delete an item, the list containing the data seems to update correctly but the corresponding UI incorrectly removes the absolute last item displayed instead of the actual item that you clicked to delete. This problem seems to happen with `TextFormField` specifically.

I have included below a sample app that illustrates the problem. To test, just install [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get/install), then run the app (I run it as a Web app). Once the app is running, in the left column (named '**Using TextFormFields**'), try to delete items and you'll see the problem -- it is always the last item displayed that deletes, even if you click to delete the first item. For comparison, I have included on right side a set up using `ListTile`s instead of `TextFormField`s and that works without a problem.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs with `TextFormField` specifically? Do you know how to solve this? Thanks in advance for any help!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}

class OverviewPageController extends GetxController {

  final itemsList = [
    Item(id: 0, name: 'Item 1'),
    Item(id: 1, name: 'Item 2'),
    Item(id: 2, name: 'Item 3'),
    Item(id: 3, name: 'Item 4'),
  ].obs;

  void deleteItem(Item item) {
    int index = itemsList.indexOf(item);
    var itemRemoved = itemsList.removeAt(index);
    print('item deleted: ${itemRemoved.name}');
    itemsList.refresh();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: OverviewPage(),
    );
  }
}

class OverviewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const OverviewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Expanded(child: TextFormFieldsSection()),
              SizedBox(width: 40),
              Expanded(child: ListTilesSection()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListTilesSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListTilesSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller1 = Get.put(OverviewPageController(), tag: '1');

    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Using ListTiles', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Obx(
              () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: controller1.itemsList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(controller1.itemsList[index].name),
                    trailing: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () => controller1.deleteItem(controller1.itemsList[index]),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TextFormFieldsSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFormFieldsSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller2 = Get.put(OverviewPageController(), tag: '2');

    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Using TextFormFields', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Obx(
              () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: controller2.itemsList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12)
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            readOnly: true,
                            initialValue: controller2.itemsList[index].name,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                          ),
                        ),
                        OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () => controller2.deleteItem(controller2.itemsList[index]),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                ],
              );

            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to wrap with Obx or getbuilder which identify a variable to be change on state

Comment: @ArbiterChil You must have missed it -- both of the ListView.builders are indeed wrapped with Obx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're code is totally right and should work fine, it's Flutter that doesn't know which widget to exactly delete, I will explain:

when Flutter engine notices that an existent element in the tree is deleted from the tree ( which your code does ) it look to replace it with some other widget with it's same `runtimeType`, so when you wanna delete a `TextFormField`, Flutter mistaken the exact widget to remove even if your code is totally fine.

This behavior is really helpful for performance in most cases, to avoid extra necessary builds in the tree when it should.

**The Answer of your problem** is by telling Flutter that each `TextFormField` is unique from all others, by assigning a unique `Key` to the TextFormField, Here is your new code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}

class OverviewPageController extends GetxController {
  final itemsList = [
    Item(id: 0, name: 'Item 1'),
    Item(id: 1, name: 'Item 2'),
    Item(id: 2, name: 'Item 3'),
    Item(id: 3, name: 'Item 4'),
  ].obs;

  void deleteItem(Item item) {
    int index = itemsList.indexOf(item);
    var itemRemoved = itemsList.removeAt(index);
    print('item deleted: ${itemRemoved.name}');
    itemsList.refresh();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: OverviewPage(),
    );
  }
}

class OverviewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const OverviewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Expanded(child: TextFormFieldsSection()),
              SizedBox(width: 40),
              Expanded(child: ListTilesSection()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListTilesSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListTilesSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller1 = Get.put(OverviewPageController(), tag: '1');

    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Using ListTiles',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Obx(
          () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: controller1.itemsList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                key: UniqueKey(), // add UniqueKey()
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    title: Text(controller1.itemsList[index].name),
                    trailing: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () =>
                          controller1.deleteItem(controller1.itemsList[index]),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TextFormFieldsSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFormFieldsSection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller2 = Get.put(OverviewPageController(), tag: '2');

    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Using TextFormFields',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Obx(
          () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: controller2.itemsList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12)),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            key: UniqueKey(), // add UniqueKey()
                            readOnly: true,
                            initialValue: controller2.itemsList[index].name,
                            decoration:
                                const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                          ),
                        ),
                        OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () => controller2
                              .deleteItem(controller2.itemsList[index]),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Note the `UniqueKey()` I assigned to widgets, now run your app again and it should work as you expect.

Please, refer also to those topics:

[When to Use Keys - Flutter Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)

[Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html)

Comment: Ah, never thought of that. Thanks for the well explained answer! It solved the problem. Much appreciated.